# Error en validación, no se oculta mensaje de error con javascript

Tags: jquery, html5

Ahora con el código que he puesto, al dejar en blanco los campos no se pone el borde rojo de los input y cuando escribo en un campo desaparecen los mensajes de error en los otros campos.......

```js
jQuery.noConflict();
var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre");
var correo = document.getElementById("correo");
var mensaje = document.getElementById("mensaje");


jQuery(document).on('click', '#enviar', function($) 
{
 


 jQuery("#nombre").on("input", function() 
 { 
  if(jQuery("#nombre").val().length < 4)
  {
      jQuery("#nombre").css("border", "3px solid red");
      jQuery(".msgerror1").css("visibility", "visible");
     
  }
  else
  {
   jQuery("#nombre").css("border", "1px solid ");
   jQuery(".msgerror1").css("visibility", "hidden");
  }
});

 jQuery("#correo").on("input", function() 
 { 
  if(jQuery("#correo").val().length < 4)
  {
      
      jQuery("#correo").css("border", "3px solid red");
      jQuery(".msgerror1").css("visibility", "visible");

  }
  else
  {
   jQuery("#correo").css("border", "1px solid ");
   jQuery(".msgerror1").css("visibility", "hidden");
  }
});

 jQuery("#mensaje").on("input", function() 
 { 

  if(jQuery("#mensaje").val().length == 0)
  {
      
   
      jQuery("#mensaje").css("border", "3px solid red");
      jQuery(".msgerror1").css("visibility", "visible");
  }
  else
  {
   jQuery("#mensaje").css("border", "1px solid ");
   jQuery(".msgerror1").css("visibility", "hidden");
  }
});
 
 if(jQuery("#privacidad")!== 'acepto')
 {
     
  
   
     jQuery(".msgerror1").css("visibility", "visible");
 }
 else
 {
  
  jQuery(".msgerror1").css("visibility", "hidden");
 }
});
```

```css
.msgerror1
{
 color: red;
 visibility: hidden;
 font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post" id="myform" ><!-- onsubmit="return enviarform();"> -->
   <ul class="ulformu">
    <li  class="liformu"> 
     <label for="nombre"></label>
     
      
            <input name="nombre" id="nombre" type="text" placeholder="Nombre*" autofocus=""  >
     <p class="msgerror1">el campo nombre es obligatorio</p>
    </li>
    <li class="tlf liformu">
     <label for="correo"></label>
      
            <input name="correo" id="correo" type="email" placeholder="Correo*" >
             <p class="msgerror1">El campo correo es obligatorio</p>
             


     
    </li>
    <li>
     
    </li>
    <li class="liformu">
     <textarea name="mensaje" id="mensaje"  placeholder="¿En que te puedo ayudar?*"></textarea>
      <p class="msgerror1">el mensaje es obligatorio</p>
    </li>

    <li>
     <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="privacidad" value="acepto"> <label for="cbox2">He leído y acepto la <a target="_blank" class="po" href="http://localhost/adela/politica-de-privacidad/">política de uso de datos</a></label>
     <p class="msgerror1">Tienes que aceptar la política de uso de datos</p>
    </li>
    
    <li class="liformu boton">
      <input id="enviar" type="submit" value="Enviar" />
    </li>
   </ul> 
  </form>
```

```
if(jQuery("#mensaje").val().length < 6)
    {


        jQuery("#mensaje").css("border", "3px solid red");
        jQuery(".msgerror1").css("visibility", "visible");
    }
    else
    {
        jQuery("#mensaje").css("border", "1px solid ");
        jQuery(".msgerror1").css("visibility", "hidden");
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="liformu">
                    <textarea name="mensaje" id="mensaje"  placeholder="¿En que te puedo ayudar?*"></textarea>
                        <p class="msgerror1">el mensaje es obligatorio</p>
                </li>
```

podeis verlo aqui www.adela.insertcoinproductos.com en contacto, dadle a enviar sin rellenar algun campo y os saldrá el mensaje y luego rellenad el campo mensaje y no desaparece. llevo un rato mirando el código y no encuentro el fallo......

Comment: No entiendo, qué mensaje de error? que quieres que suceda? Ademas, no pongas enlaces a otras paginas. Tú pregunta deberia contener toda la informacion relevante para su resolución

Comment: ok no pondré mas enlaces a otras paginas.... lo que quiero que ocura es que cuando se escriba en el campo mensaje y si aun en otro campo obligatorio no esta relleno que desaparezca el mensaje de error

Comment: Pero en tu codigo, ahora mismo está ejecutando `length < 6` y en efecto 0 (no tienes nada escrito) es menor que 6 asi que el mensaje de error se muestra. Quieres que cambie en cuanto empieces a escribir¿?

Comment: ok entiendo voy a modificar el código...

Comment: Intenta agregando un metodo en el KeyUP del textarea que active el metodo que tienes arrvia,

Comment: Parece que lo único que te faltaría es poner tu código JS dentro de un controlador del evento change/input/keydown/keyup para el textarea, algo como `$("#mensaje").on("input", function() { ..... })`;

Comment: sigo con el problema, he puesto asi la validacion if(jQuery("#mensaje").val().length == 0)
 {
     
  
     jQuery("#mensaje").css("border", "3px solid red");
     jQuery(".msgerror1").css("visibility", "visible");
 }
 else
 {
  jQuery("#mensaje").css("border", "1px solid ");
  jQuery(".msgerror1").css("visibility", "hidden");
 } pero no desaparece el mensaje

Comment: @RafaelHernández tienes varias respuestas funcionales a tu pregunta

Comment: alvaro montoro con tu código me vale cuando sale un mensaje de error y escribo en el campo , instantaneamente desaparece el mensaje pero si tengo 3 mensajes en 3 campos y escribo en un campo desaparecen en todos, voy a editar mi pregunta para poner como tengo ahora el código

Comment: @Rafael, en mi respuesta ves como solucionar que no se quiten los 3 mensajes a la vez.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como dijo Alvaro Montoro en los comentarios, si añades un evento `input` puedes ir analizando la longitud del texto a medida que vas introduciendo caracteres

**Respecto al UPDATE en la pregunta**

Todos tus codigos de mensaje se llaman `msgerror1` por eso se aplica a todos los cambios. Pon nombres individuales y podrás controlarlos a cada uno independientemente

```js
jQuery.noConflict();
var nombre = document.getElementById("nombre");
var correo = document.getElementById("correo");
var mensaje = document.getElementById("mensaje");


jQuery(document).on('click', '#enviar', function($) {


    if (jQuery("#nombre").val().length < 4) {
        jQuery("#nombre").css("border", "3px solid red");
        jQuery(".msgerror1").css("visibility", "visible");
    }
    if (jQuery("#correo").val().length < 4) {
        jQuery("#correo").css("border", "3px solid red");
        jQuery(".msgerror2").css("visibility", "visible");
    }
    if (jQuery("#mensaje").val().length == 0) {
        jQuery("#mensaje").css("border", "3px solid red");
        jQuery(".msgerror3").css("visibility", "visible");
    }

    jQuery("#nombre").on("input", function() {
        if (jQuery("#nombre").val().length < 4) {
            jQuery("#nombre").css("border", "3px solid red");
            jQuery(".msgerror1").css("visibility", "visible");

        } else {
            jQuery("#nombre").css("border", "1px solid ");
            jQuery(".msgerror1").css("visibility", "hidden");
        }
    });

    jQuery("#correo").on("input", function() {
        if (jQuery("#correo").val().length < 4) {

            jQuery("#correo").css("border", "3px solid red");
            jQuery(".msgerror2").css("visibility", "visible");

        } else {
            jQuery("#correo").css("border", "1px solid ");
            jQuery(".msgerror2").css("visibility", "hidden");
        }
    });

    jQuery("#mensaje").on("input", function() {

        if (jQuery("#mensaje").val().length == 0) {


            jQuery("#mensaje").css("border", "3px solid red");
            jQuery(".msgerror3").css("visibility", "visible");
        } else {
            jQuery("#mensaje").css("border", "1px solid ");
            jQuery(".msgerror3").css("visibility", "hidden");
        }
    });

    if (!document.getElementById('privacidad').checked) {


        jQuery(".msgerror4").css("visibility", "visible");
    } else {

        jQuery(".msgerror4").css("visibility", "hidden");
    }
});
```

```css
p.msgerror1, p.msgerror2, p.msgerror3, p.msgerror4
{
 color: red;
 visibility: hidden;
 font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post" id="myform">
    <!-- onsubmit="return enviarform();"> -->
    <ul class="ulformu">
        <li class="liformu">
            <label for="nombre"></label>


            <input name="nombre" id="nombre" type="text" placeholder="Nombre*" autofocus="">
            <p class="msgerror1">el campo nombre es obligatorio</p>
        </li>
        <li class="tlf liformu">
            <label for="correo"></label>

            <input name="correo" id="correo" type="email" placeholder="Correo*">
            <p class="msgerror2">El campo correo es obligatorio</p>




        </li>

        <li class="liformu">
            <textarea name="mensaje" id="mensaje" placeholder="¿En que te puedo ayudar?*"></textarea>
            <p class="msgerror3">el mensaje es obligatorio</p>
        </li>

        <li>
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="privacidad" value="acepto">
            <label for="cbox2">He leído y acepto la <a target="_blank" class="po" href="http://localhost/adela/politica-de-privacidad/">política de uso de datos</a>
            </label>
            <p class="msgerror4">Tienes que aceptar la política de uso de datos</p>
        </li>

        <li class="liformu boton">
            <input id="enviar" type="submit" value="Enviar" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4):

Con el evento `input`, se activa mientras escribes en el campo

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#mensaje").on("input",function(){

if($("#mensaje").val().length < 6)
    {


        $("#mensaje").css("border", "3px solid red");
        $(".msgerror1").css("visibility", "visible");
    }
    else
    {
        $("#mensaje").css("border", "1px solid ");
        $(".msgerror1").css("visibility", "hidden");
    }
});
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="liformu">
                    <textarea name="mensaje" id="mensaje"  placeholder="¿En que te puedo ayudar?*"></textarea>
                        <p class="msgerror1">el mensaje es obligatorio</p>
                </li>
```

Con el evento `focus` se activa cuando te encuentras en el campo

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#mensaje").focus(function(){

if($("#mensaje").val().length < 6)
    {


        $("#mensaje").css("border", "3px solid red");
        $(".msgerror1").css("visibility", "visible");
    }
    else
    {
        $("#mensaje").css("border", "1px solid ");
        $(".msgerror1").css("visibility", "hidden");
    }
});
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="liformu">
                    <textarea name="mensaje" id="mensaje"  placeholder="¿En que te puedo ayudar?*"></textarea>
                        <p class="msgerror1">el mensaje es obligatorio</p>
                </li>
```

Comment: no quita el mensaje, que es lo que quiere el OP

Comment: @lois6b si quita haciendo focus nuevamente al campo

Comment: entonces tienes que salirte del campo y volver a entrar para que lo valide? pudiendo simplemente escribir y se quite? No has explicado ademas tu codigo. Solo lo has pegado

Comment: @lois6b de acuerdo a su descripcion del problema dice que sale de foco haciendo click, y luego vuelve al campo pero no se elimina el mensaje. `podeis verlo aqui www.adela.insertcoinproductos.com en contacto, dadle a enviar sin rellenar algun campo y os saldrá el mensaje y luego rellenad el campo mensaje y no desaparece. llevo un rato mirando el código y no encuentro el fallo......`

Comment: @lois6b de todos modos puse dos ejemplos, que son practicamente muy similares

Answer (score 3):

tu codigo está bien, quizá solo te falte hacer una acción que disparé esa validación puedes hacerlo con un keyup.

```
            <script> 
            $( "#mensaje" ).keyup(function() {
                 if(jQuery("#mensaje").val().length < 6) {
                    jQuery("#mensaje").css("border", "3px solid red");
                    jQuery(".msgerror1").css("visibility", "visible");
                } else {
                    jQuery("#mensaje").css("border", "1px solid ");
                    jQuery(".msgerror1").css("visibility", "hidden");
                } 
            });
            </script>
```